# Find oldest record by customer?

Tags: sql, sql-server

for my SQL Server 2016 project I have an Orders table looks like the one below and I want to create a SQL query that shows the oldest order for each customer / product. There are thousands of orders in the Orders table today and I should expect this to grow in size so I want this to perform well.

The goal is the output to look like this:

| OrderID | CustomerID | ProductID | OrderDt | OrderAmt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 1 | 1/1/2021 | $50 |
| 456 | 1 | 2 | 1/2/2021 | $20 |
| 345 | 2 | 1 | 1/1/2021 | $30 |

The data in the Orders table today look like this:

| OrderID | CustomerID | ProductID | OrderDt | OrderAmt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 1 | 1/1/2021 | $50 |
| 758 | 1 | 1 | 1/2/2021 | $80 |
| 563 | 1 | 2 | 1/3/2021 | 74 |
| 684 | 1 | 2 | 1/4/2021 | 23 |
| 456 | 1 | 2 | 1/2/2021 | $20 |
| 345 | 2 | 1 | 1/1/2021 | $30 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical method is to use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customerid, productid order by orderdt, orderid) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

With an index on `(customerid, productid, orderdt)`, then a correlated subquery might be a smidgen faster:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.orderdt = (select min(t2.orderdt)
                   from t t2
                   where t2.productid = t.productid and t2.customerid = t.customerid
                  );
```

Or a slightly less performance method without subqueries:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by productid, customerid order by orderdt);
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, I like the 2nd approach but I seem to be getting dupes. Should it be orderdt or orderid? I would think min orderdt but filter on orderid?

Comment: It depends on how you are defining "oldest".  Clearly you have duplicates on the `orderdt` based on your comment.  If `orderid` is an `identity` column, then it should be ordered the same as `orderdt` and you can use that instead.